# TortiseSVN - At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortiseSVN to access our repository. The rest of my office is running the same OS (Windows 7), they're all running TortiseSVN (either v. 1.7.? or 1.8.?) and none of them have any issues. Here are the issues I've been having:

I was running TortiseSVN 1.8.5 and for some reason started getting a 503 error when I would try to update, telling me the repository was temporarily unavailable. The whole time I was still able to access the repository going through my browser.

After researching the issue, I tried clearing the saved data which didn't work, I uninstalled and cleared out the AppData cache before reinstalling, and I uninstalled it with Total Uninstall to make sure every bit of it was cleared off my machine before I reinstalled it, and always had the same issue.

I tried switching down to v. 1.7.13 in case it was some strange issue with version compatibility. With v. 1.7 I am able to access the repository and pull down the code, but when I try to commit I get an error saying:

```
Error    Commit failed (details follow):
Error    At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
Error    Server sent unexpected return value (400 Bad Request) in response to PROPATCH
Error    request for '/svn/projects/!svn/txn/26110-kb1'
```

This is a completely clean pull-down, all I did to test it was add a comment into one file and try to commit. So this should be a completely fresh repo.

I checked the versions of TortiseSVN other people in the office were running and some are on 1.8.5, some on 1.8.4 and some on 1.8.3. So I've also tried installing each of the other 1.8 versions others are running and always get the 503 temporarily unavailable error.

Does anybody have any ideas for me? I'm completely at a loss at this point.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the property value you're attempting to set? Can it be set by the other users of your repository?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not trying to set any property. I pull down the repository fresh and just comment out one line of code in a file and try to check that file in and it gives me that error. So unless it has to do with checking it in from v. 1.7 instead of 1.8, I'm not sure what it would be trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: did you try "Check for Modifications" on the folder, and check "Properties" in the dialog box?
Tortoise SVN (and the svn command line program) will update some properties automatically.
Perhaps this is one of those situations.

Comment: I checked as you suggested and it didn't find any modifications, even with the "Properties" box selected except for the one code change I made.